# Odd undefined reference errors

Tags: c++, linker-errors, sfml

Alright I will try to describe my problem in detail.
I've started using a ziploading API for SFML in order to read game resources from an archive, I've placed all required headers and source files in my project in Codeblocks, so my project consists of the following:

```
Source files for game
ZipLoader.h
ZipLoader.cpp
ioapi.h
unzip.h
zconf.h
zlib.h
```

So in my game menu header, where I attempt to draw a game menu based on resources in the archive, I have this:

```
    #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
    #include "Globals.h"
    #include "ZipLoader.h"

class GameMenu
{
    private:
    Zip::File file();

}
```

Which is basically, where I tried to initialize a zip file so I can load from it in gameMenu.cpp where I declared my menu. **However** I'm getting some very weird errors in ZipLoader.cpp, which are as follows:

```
src\ZipLoader.cpp|81|undefined reference to `unzOpen'|
src\ZipLoader.cpp|89|undefined reference to `unzLocateFile'|
src\ZipLoader.cpp|94|undefined reference to `unzOpenCurrentFile'|
src\ZipLoader.cpp|100|undefined reference to `unzGetCurrentFileInfo'|
src\ZipLoader.cpp|105|undefined reference to `unzReadCurrentFile'|
src\ZipLoader.cpp|109|undefined reference to `unzCloseCurrentFile'|
src\ZipLoader.cpp|110|undefined reference to `unzClose'|
```

But I find that impossible, I figured I'm missing the library but I have it imported in the file that's giving me errors, all the methods listed above are located in `unzip.h` which is imported in the file that is giving me errors as seen bellow:

```
#include "ZipLoader.h"
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "unzip.h"

...
unzFile ZipHandle=unzOpen(DataFile); // error????
```

And as you can see bellow, in unzip.h these references exist very well:

```
extern unzFile ZEXPORT unzOpen OF((const char *path));
extern unzFile ZEXPORT unzOpen2 OF((const char *path,
                                    zlib_filefunc_def* pzlib_filefunc_def));
    extern int ZEXPORT unzClose OF((unzFile file));
```

This is by far the oddest error I've ever gotten in a C++ program, how can it be undefined when it's right there? (I'm using Windows XP SP3)

Comment: Did you *link* the library? You said you added the headers...but did you copy the libraries (`.lib`/`.dll` files)? Headers only describe what's in the library; the library contains the actual code.

Comment: I didn't, let me check if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Nope, it didn't fix the problem. :(

Comment: You'd have to copy the libraries and reference them in your IDE.

Comment: Still didn't manage to fix the problem because I have no dll files or library files, the framework I downloaded supposingly only needs these files, which I already included.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you forgot to add the zlib to the library list.

If you're using MSVC, go to your project settings, open the Linker settings and add zlib.lib (I believe this is the filename of libz for win32) to the additional dependencies.

If you're using gcc, add `-lzlib` (or was it `-lz` ?) to your commandline.

Comment: It is `-lz` with GCC (the library is called `libz` on disk).

Comment: I didn't even have zlib installed, after downloading it I found no DLL or .lib files whatsoever, where can I get them from? I probably can't add a dependency without it installed.

Comment: Where did you get the "zlib.h" from, then?

Comment: @Mark it was packed in the ZipLoader framework, which also came with some DLLs, which I have added to the project folder already. I also downloaded zlib DLLs from the internet and added them to system32 and still nothing.

Comment: ZipLoader? Isn't that Java? Whatever, it's not sufficient to copy the files to your project folder. You need to set them up in the project settings as described in my answer above (e.g. Project settings, Linker settings, etc). To be more specific, you need to specify the .LIB file (not the DLL) there.

Answer (score 1):

You have your functions declared in a header file so you should not have compiling error.  Your problem is that in the linking process, you are not including the libraries that contains the implementation of those functions.

You have to know where are those files and include them in the linking process.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem with unzGoToFirstFile. If you download the ZLib sources and do a simple "grep -irl unzGoToFirstFile" you'll find that these functions are not part of ZLib at all. They are however part of a contributed library called minizip found within the ZLib sources.

Add this to the ZLib CMakeLists.txt somwhere near the bottom and it will create a library called "libunzip.a" with the required unzGoToFirstFile etc functions you require. Just link your program towards that and you should be golden.

```
set(UNZIP_SOURCES "contrib/minizip/unzip.c"
"contrib/minizip/zip.c"
"contrib/minizip/ioapi.c")
set(UNZIP_HEADERS "contrib/minizip/unzip.h"
"contrib/minizip/zip.h"
"contrib/minizip/ioapi.h")

add_library(unzip STATIC 
"${UNZIP_SOURCES}"
"${UNZIP_HEADERS}")

target_link_libraries(unzip zlibstatic)

install(TARGETS unzip
RUNTIME DESTINATION "${INSTALL_BIN_DIR}"
ARCHIVE DESTINATION "${INSTALL_LIB_DIR}"
LIBRARY DESTINATION "${INSTALL_LIB_DIR}" )

install(FILES ${UNZIP_HEADERS} DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include")
```